# Job with just the reducer phase?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop MapReduce the intermediate output (map output) is saved in the local disk. I would like to know if it is possible to start a job just with the reduce phase, that reads the mapoutput from the local disk, partition the data and execute the reduce tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a basic implementation of Mapper called [IdentityMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html) , which essentially passes all the key-value pairs to a Reducer.

- Reducer reads the outputs generated by the different mappers as  pairs and emits key value pairs.
- The Reducer’s job is to process the data that comes from the mapper.
- If MapReduce programmer do not set the Mapper Class using JobConf.setMapperClass then IdentityMapper.class is used as a default value.

You can't run just reducers without any mappers..

Comment: I  can't find any example with the identity mapper. I have googled it, or use the github. Can you point me any example?

Comment: @xeon http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Custo
mizing+How+Lines+are+Split+into+Key%2FValue+Pairs

Answer (score 0):

Map reduce works on data which is in HDFS. So I dont think you can write reducer only map reduce to read from local disk

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hadoop Streaming, you can just add:

```
-mapper "/bin/sh -c \"cat\""
```